# PHP page bookmark with GET

Tags: javascript, php, html

1) Why does the URL show "&submit=Submit" at the end? What should be done to get only the two variables name and age?

2) Does isset function work well with GET method as well? Is there another function or way to handle this?

Result screenshot
[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>My first PHP page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
   Age: <input type="text" name="age"/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_GET['submit']) ) { //was the form submitted?

        echo "Welcome ". $_GET["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "You are ". $_GET["age"] . "years old<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: because that's how it works? whats the problem here? `isset` works with any variables and your screen shot shows it working -so um

Comment: That's happening because your `<form>` is using `method="GET"` If you use `method="POST"`, the data will not be sent in the URL. You should Google around to find out more about how HTML forms work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The URL is showing variable -> value key pairs. The `name=` attribute supplies the var name, the element value provides the value.  Remove the `name=` from the submit button. Problem solved.
2. Yes, isset works with both GET and POST methods.

Comment: Thank you sir for the great solution. I removed the name= from submit button. Then in my isset function I used:    if ( isset($_GET['name']) )   and it works!! I hope it is legal and good practice.